# Adding attachment using Swiftmailer

Tags: 8

I am trying to add an attachment to an email from a form_submit. I can see the attachment loading in the hook_mail() before the email sends, but no attachment is coming through. I also tried to use the swiftmailer_swiftmailer_attach() hook and that doesn't work. The emails are coming over with Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

Here is the code:

```
// from submitForm()
$params['message'] = $body;
$mail_manager = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('plugin.manager.mail');

$mail_manager->mail('so_assets', 'banner_email', 'test@test.com', \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId(), [
  //'content_type' => "text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes",
  'from' => 'test@test.com',
  'message' => $body,
  'myattachment' => $store_logo[0],
]);


// in .module file
function so_assets_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
  );
  //var_dump($params['myattachment']); die(); // I can see the managed file ID here and load it.
  switch ($key) {
    case 'banner_email':
      $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
      $message['subject'] = t('New Request');
      $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
      //$message['params']['files'][] = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($params['myattachment']);
      break;
  }
}
// I tried this, with and without the file attachment commented out in the hook_mail()
function so_assets_swiftmailer_attach($key) {
  return \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load(5130);
}
```

Comment: For media attachments, do you need to set the header and content data appropriately (multipart/mixed etc) or does SwiftMailer interpret this and do it for you? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113666/how-to-attach-pdf-to-email-using-swiftmailer-in-symfony2

Comment: According to the README, that hook should work. As long as you cleared cache it should fire. You might want to use a debugger to step through the code and see that it actually does fire. However, there is an open issue here too related to what you are asking: https://www.drupal.org/node/2841672 PS, you will want to evaluate what the mail $key is in the attach hook so that you are not attaching that to every outgoing email via SwiftMailer.

Comment: Kevin, are you saying that I should be using the attach hook and not just trying to add the attachment in the case statement? I am looking at that issue and trying to figure out if it applies, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swiftmailer currently expects a plain \stdClass object in files as this part hasn't been fully ported from D7. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2713651.

So you need to do something like

```
$file = (object) [
'filename' => $file->getFilename(),
'uri' => $file->getFileUri(),
'filemime' => $file->getMimeType(),
];
$message['params']['files'][] = $file;
```

Comment: Yep, thank you. I finally figured that out. I was going to submit a patch to swiftmailer module to fix the SwiftMailer.php file. I will probably just do something similar to what you have posted here in the meantime. You beat me to my own answer!

Comment: Would be great if you find time to work on the issue there and update the patch based on my feedback.

Comment: I would upvote that answer 10 times if I could.

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth mentioning that if you have generated contents rather than a Drupal file, you have to use an array rather than a stdClass, and insert it into "attachments" rather than "files", for example

```
$file = [
    'filename' => $filename,
    'filemime' => $mimetype,
    'filecontent' => $contents,
] ;
$message['params']['attachments'][] = $file ;
```

I was getting crazy to get it to work, luckily I could look at Swiftmailer code, which is very clear.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you it worked for me.